# Create different combinations based on a list - no repeats

Tags: excel, vba, combinations, permutation

Im looking to automatically generate set of combination based on a define list, but must have unique and showing all possible results

example

Col A

```
Conor 
Can
Patrick
Ben
```

Results looking like this:

```
conor - can
conor - Patrick
Consuner - Ben
conor - can - Patrick
conor - can - Ben
```

e.x. I don't want to see "can - Conor" because we already have " Conor - can"

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt. Please see [ask] and [reprex] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 2):

In **A2** enter:

```
=DEC2BIN(ROW()-2,4)
```

and copy downward.  In **B2** enter:

```
=MID($A2,COLUMN()-1,1)
```

and copy across and then down.  In **F2** enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" - ",TRUE,IF(B2:E2="1",$B$1:$E$1,""))
```

and copy downwards.

Finally in **B1** through **E1** enter your four names:

[image]

**Note:**

This uses a **binary number pattern** to generate all 2<sup>N</sup>-1 combinations.

Comment: Had done the same, and was spinning my wheels to get it into a single dynamic array formula. But TEXTJOIN would not play nice.  BTW, with the dynamic array formula the array in B2:E17 can be done with: `=--MID(DEC2BIN(SEQUENCE(2^4-1),4),{1,2,3,4},1)` in just B2

Comment: @ScottCraner  Great idea! thanks